# Stop MySQL within Docker without stopping Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm running MySQL within a Docker container and would like to stop MySQL so I can run myisamchk to repair a table. But when I stop MySQL the Docker container stops also. Can I keep the container running whist MySQL is stopped?

Comment: mysql Dockerfile has CMD ["mysqld"] and entrypoint as [this](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh), thus stopping mysql ought to stop the container, you can create another image using mysql and start tailing /dev/null, thereby stopping mysql in a new container won't stop the container itself

Comment: You may also mount the mysql container's volume in a temporary container using `docker run` to execute your commands on that database.

Answer (score 3):

This will tell your container to stop the MySQL daemon:

```
docker exec CONTAINERNAME /usr/sbin/mysqld stop
```

This just stops the MySQL daemon; the container itself will continue to run.

To restart the MySQL daemon:

```
docker exec CONTAINERNAME /usr/sbin/mysqld start
```

Comment: @ShinDapaty You might have to use sudo to run the command as root: `docker exec 9eb7765a7f47 sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld stop`.

Comment: still same issue docker exec 9eb7765a7f47 /usr/sbin/mysqld stop 2022-01-21 10:04:52 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (server 10.6.5-MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~focal) starting as process 74 ... 2022-01-21 10:04:52 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive /usr/sbin/mysqld: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root! 2022-01-21 10:04:52 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: @ShinDapaty Try `docker exec -u 0 9eb7765a7f47 /usr/sbin/mysqld stop`. This will run as root.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you store table data, but did you try with,

docker run -it  and running /bin/sh

for example,

```
docker run -it MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="test_root" /bin/sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Try any of following commands

```
docker rm -f &lt;Container Id&gt;
```

or

```
docker kill &lt;Container Id&gt;* <br>
```

Example:

```
docker rm -f 2496eb2fb98ae3bd702733216ab267e3a82bc5b2bd629dbb214a08a63df8bb11
```

or

```
docker kill 2496eb2fb98ae3bd702733216ab267e3a82bc5b2bd629dbb214a08a63df8bb11*
```

Comment: OP asked to keep the container running, with the daemon shut down.